# Using flex with React

Tags: css, reactjs

I have the following code

```html
<div className="noti-messages w-100">
    <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <span style={{ 'fontWeight': 800 }} className="noti-msg-title">Prices Approved</span>
        <NotifyMsgDate className="noti-msg-date" data-date="somedate"> Some dates </NotifyMsgDate>
    </div>
</div>
<div className="d-flex align-items-center mt-2">
    <p className="noti-msg-description mt-0 mr-1">Some Description</p>
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/notification">- Review</a>
</div>
```

The CSS provided in the className is not taking any impact. How would I rewrite the following code to use React Flex?

i.e `w-100` , `justify-content-between`

Comment: Where did you define the .w-100 class?

Comment: @hurricane it's defined in my bootstrap.css file

Comment: If the class is being applied to the element then it _should_ be working... where is the failure?  Is the `class` not being applied, or the styles associated with the class?

Comment: `align-items-center` and `justify-content-between` is not taking any impact @AlexanderNied

Comment: how did you import bootstrap.css?

Comment: You might consider adding a [tag:bootstrap] tag to this question.  How exactly are you adding bootstrap?  Are other bootstrap classes/styles being applied?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-between">

display:flex;
width: 100%,
justify-content: space-between;

<div className="d-flex align-items-center mt-2">

display:flex;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 2rem;

<p className="noti-msg-description mt-0 mr-1">Some Description</p>

margin-top: 0;
margin-right: 1rem;
```